# Pull data from firebase sub-collection into a list.item in React Native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

**Hello there guys**
I'm currently trying to pull data from sub collection in Firestore, i have a query(which i would like you to check) and the goal is to present the data from the sub collection in a list.

1 - The Query that insert data is this(Working good):

```
      const { uid } = currentUser;
    const [business, setBusinesss] = useState(null);
    const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');
    const [pendingClients, setpendingClients] = useState([]);

    const takedata = () => {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection('users')
            .where('phone', '==', phone)
            .where('accountType', '==', 'business')
            .get()
            .then((snapshot) => {
                if (!snapshot.empty) {
                    snapshot.docs[0].ref
                        .collection('pending-clients')
                        .doc(uid)
                        .set({
                            uid,
                            name: currentUser.name,
                            lastName: currentUser.lastName,
                            phone: currentUser.phone,
                        });
                } else console.log('Phone dosent exist');
                //setBusinesssName(snapshot.data().name);
                setLoading(false);
            });
    };

And this the query for pulling out the data:


    const [pendingClients, setpendingClients] = useState([]);

  const pullData = () => {
    firebase.firestore().ref;
    firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("users")
      .where("accountType", "==", "business")
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        if (!snapshot.empty) {
          snapshot.docs[0].ref.collection("pending-clients").doc(uid).get({
            uid,
            name: pendingClients.name,
            lastName: pendingClients.lastName,
            phone: pendingClients.phone,
          });
        } else console.log("No Users Are currently pending.");
        setLoading(false);
      });
  };
```

After i will pull the data out i want to display the data(if its 1 user or 999 i want to display it in a list.)

```
 return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <Text>PendingClients screen</Text>
  <List.Item
    title={pullData.phone}
    description={pullData.lastName}
    left={(props) => <List.Icon {...props} icon="folder" />}
  />
</View>
```

I cant figure out what to do, its seems that the query is not good at all.

Comment: have you been able to output to the console the values retrieved from the consult?

Comment: No i haven't :( i think the query is the problem

Comment: could you post your collections structure please?